# Data not getting in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I am developing an application in C# VS 2010.

I have below code to fetch the student details with some name into the datagridview.

```
var CommandText = @"SELECT sid as 'Student ID', name as 'Student Name', adDate as 
                  'Admission Date',
               paidFees as 'Fees Paid', balance as 'Fees Remaining'
                   FROM Student WHERE (status = '" + status + "') AND 
                   (name LIKE '%'+'"+txtSearchName.Text.Trim() + "'+'%')";
string select = CommandText;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, con); 

            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            dgvSearch.ReadOnly = true;
            dgvSearch.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

My problem is I am just getting headers of the table not data like below screenshot.
[image: Search]

What is be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a parameterized query.

```
var CommandText = @"SELECT sid as 'Student ID', name as 'Student Name', adDate as 
                  'Admission Date', paidFees as 'Fees Paid', balance as 'Fees Remaining'
                   FROM Student WHERE (status = @status) AND (name LIKE @stuname)";
string select = CommandText;
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, con); 
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuname", "%" + txtSearchName.Text.Trim() + "%");
SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
....
```

In this way the problems with string concatenation of quotes and wildcard chars for the LIKE statement are greatly simplified and you avoid subtle errors like the wrong quotes around the `%` char.

Of course this removes any possible [SQL Injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should drop `'` after opening `%` and before closing `%`.

```
var CommandText = @"SELECT sid as 'Student ID', name as 'Student Name', adDate as 
              'Admission Date',
              paidFees as 'Fees Paid', balance as 'Fees Remaining'
              FROM Student WHERE (status = '" + status + @"') AND 
              (name LIKE '%" + name + "%')";
```

`LIKE` part should be of form `LIKE '%somename%'`.

Also it us good practice to wrap SqlConnection with `using` construct so that you never forget to dispose of it (even when exception is thrown.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
}
```